# Need help identifying SMD component

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

This is a board from a Johnny Lightning V-bot, it has these SMD 6 pin components that just have a M03 and a dot on one of the terminals. Does anyone have a datasheet or any idea on how to ask for one to replace it? It helps with switching direction on a motor that transforms the upper half, and it's right on top of the hip motor connector.

This is the component, roughly 2.9 mm by 1.5 mm:

[image: Picture 1]

This is where it goes:

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely an ROHM [QS6M3](https://www.mouser.de/ds/2/348/qs6m3-1018178.pdf) dual N+P channel MOSFET.

[image]

Comment: thanks! gonna search those!!!

Comment: You're welcome. The datasheet I linked is on Mouser's website so that might be a hint as to a source.